# Python GUI not working

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI in Python but for some reason it is not working. The GUI should have an info button and a quit button. I know it is a simple error that I should be able to debug but I can't find it.

Traceback error message:

> in 
>       gu=GUI()
>
> self.info_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text="Show Info",
>   command=self.showinfo) AttributeError: 'GUI' object has no attribute
>   'showinfo'

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

class GUI:
   def __init__(self):

        #main window
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        #create two frames
        self.top_frame= tkinter.Frame()
        self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame()

        #object of StringVar class
        self.value = tkinter.StringVar()

        #top frame label
        self.info_label = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame,textvariable = self.value)

        #information button that displays the information about the name and address
        self.info_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text="Show Info", command=self.showinfo)

        #quit button that closes the program
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text ='Quit', command=self.main_window.destroy)

        #pack method for packing widgets
        self.info_label.pack()
        self.info_button.pack(side='left')      
        self.quit_button.pack(side='left')

        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame.pack()

        #main loop for running the program
        tkinter.mainloop()

def showinfo(self):
    inf = '\tSteven Marcus\n\t274 Baily Drive\n\tWaynesville, NC 27999'
    self.value.set(inf)

#call the main function
gu=GUI()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation in Python matters a lot, your indentation is off, you will need to indent the whole `def showinfo(self):` block so it goes under the `GUI` class.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

class GUI:
   def __init__(self):

        #main window
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        #create two frames
        self.top_frame= tkinter.Frame()
        self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame()

        #object of StringVar class
        self.value = tkinter.StringVar()

        #top frame label
        self.info_label = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame,textvariable = self.value)

        #information button that displays the information about the name and address
        self.info_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text="Show Info", command=self.showinfo)

        #quit button that closes the program
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text ='Quit', command=self.main_window.destroy)

        #pack method for packing widgets
        self.info_label.pack()
        self.info_button.pack(side='left')      
        self.quit_button.pack(side='left')

        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame.pack()

        #main loop for running the program
        tkinter.mainloop()

   def showinfo(self): # indent these:
        inf = '\tSteven Marcus\n\t274 Baily Drive\n\tWaynesville, NC 27999'
        self.value.set(inf)

#call the main function
gu=GUI()
```

Comment: that is how I originally had my code but I got a syntax error message that said, "unindent does not match any outer indention level". This occurs for the def showinfo(self): line. Which is what I get when I run your version.

Comment: You mixed tabs and spaces with the indentation, try it now and it will work fine. But please consider unindent everything yourself and always use 4 spaces. Right now, the first indent level is three space while the second level is 4 spaces. While the original one had `def __init__` indented 3 space while `def showinfo` had 4 spaces